# Running an IF then else loop with exceptions

Tags: vbscript

I must (will) download some hundred files from INSEE (french statistic bureau) with FDM (Free Download Manager). So I used a script to rename those downloaded files to find the five-digit-Insee-code for each commune (in the second line of the file) and put them ahead of the filename, so *rp009_cc_pop.xls* becomes *67181_rp009_cc_pop.txt*. Those downloaded .xls-files are no real Excelfiles, but plain text files with a wrong extension.
From time to time there is a downloaded file which don't have the word "commune " (with space) in their content. How can I skip the renaming of those files. So a Good advice is expensive. 
Here is the script:

```
Dim objFso, strFolder
 ' Begin Main
 Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 strFolder = objFso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)  
 If objFso.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
 Call GetJspFiles(objFso.GetFolder(strFolder))
End If
Set objFso = Nothing
' End Main

Sub GetJspFiles(ByRef objFolder)
Dim objFile, objSubFolder
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If LCase(objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "xls" Then
        Call JSPRename(objFile.Path, objFolder.Path)
    End If
Next
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
  Call GetJSPRename(objSubFolder)
Next
' objFile.Close
End Sub

Sub JSPRename(ByRef strPath, ByRef strFolder)
Dim arrText, strText, strTextLine, Position , objJspFile, newFilename, strVerz
Set objJspFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strPath)
arrText = Split(objJspFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf) ' split into lines
For Each strTextLine In arrText
  If strTextLine <> "" Then
     strText = Trim(strTextLine)
   If Instr(1,strText,"Commune ",1) Then
    Position=Instr(1, strText, "(",1)
   newFilename=mid(strText,Position+1, 5) ' 5 Characters long
   else
   end if
else
' newFilename=......  ' <== skip those files without the word 'commune ' from renaming
  end if
Next
objJspFile.Close
cutlastoff=Left(strPath, inStrRev(strPath,"\")-1)
strNewName = cutlastoff & "\" & newFilename & "_rp009_cc_pop.txt"  ' cutting the filename
Wscript.echo "New Name: " & strNewName & vbcrlf & "Old Name: " & strPath 
'!! only for Showing the results

objFSO.MoveFile strPath, strNewName
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any welcomed hint

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a nested loop inside the original for loop and any other loop to be able to skip an item.
You have to make sure the nested loop will not loop so your original script is not impacted, hence the use of a Do {...} Loop While False.

```
For Each strTextLine In arrText : Do 'Easy skip door
  If strTextLine <> "" Then
     strText = Trim(strTextLine)
   If Instr(1,strText,"Commune ",1) Then
    Position=Instr(1, strText, "(",1)
   newFilename=mid(strText,Position+1, 5) ' 5 Characters long
   else
   end if
else
   Exit Do 'Take the easy skip door
' newFilename=......  ' <== skip those files without the word 'commune ' from renaming
  end if
Loop While False : Next 'Don't forget to close the skip door.
```

---

Edit:
My apologies, I guess I was too excited to do my first post. I will leave the original post to remind me of not going too fast next time.

The below Sub will initialize a Boolean variable to False to use as a switch. It will then look for your value, set the Boolean variable to True if it finds it and will execute the rest of the code according to the value of that Boolean variable.

```
Sub JSPRename(ByRef strPath, ByRef strFolder)

    Dim boolNumberFound, arrText, strText, strTextLine, Position , objJspFile, newFilename, strVerz

    boolNumberFound = False '<-----------
    Set objJspFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strPath)
    arrText = Split(objJspFile.ReadAll, vbCrLf) ' split into lines


    For Each strTextLine In arrText
        If strTextLine <> "" Then
            strText = Trim(strTextLine)
            If Instr(1,strText,"Commune ",1) Then
                Position=Instr(1, strText, "(",1)
                newFilename=mid(strText,Position+1, 5) ' 5 Characters long
                boolNumberFound = True '<-----------
                Exit For
            end if
        end if
    Next

    If boolNumberFound Then '<-----------
        objJspFile.Close
        cutlastoff=Left(strPath, inStrRev(strPath,"\")-1)
        strNewName = cutlastoff & "\" & newFilename & "_rp009_cc_pop.txt"  ' cutting the filename
        Wscript.echo "New Name: " & strNewName & vbcrlf & "Old Name: " & strPath 
        '!! only for Showing the results

        objFSO.MoveFile strPath, strNewName
    Else
        Wscript.echo "Commune # not found in file: '" & strPath & "'. File was skipped."
    End If

End Sub
```

I also took the liberty of writing a new version of your sub using a Regular Expression object. Those are faster and more flexible. I didn't test it though. Use it to your liking.

```
Sub JSPRename(ByRef strPath, ByRef strFolder)

    Dim objJspFile, CommuneNo, arr_path, strNewName
    Dim re, re_matches, re_first_match

    Set objJspFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strPath)
    Set re = New RegExp

    re.Pattern = "(Commune *\()(\d{5})" 
    'A match will return 2 submatches:
        'submatch(0)="Commune("
        'submatch(1)=[Your 5 digits]

    Set re_matches = re.Execute(objJspFile.ReadAll)

    If re_matches.count Then 'There is at least 1 occurence
        Set re_first_match = re_matches(0)
        CommuneNo = re_first_match.SubMatches(1)
    Else
        WScript.Echo strPath & " did not contain Commnune# and was skipped."
        Exit Sub 'This exits your sub without renaming the file
    End If

    Set re = Nothing

    objJspFile.Close
    Set objJspFile = Nothing


    arr_path = Split(strPath, "\")
    arr_path(UBound(arr_path)) = CommuneNo & "_" & arr_path(UBound(arr_path))
    strNewName = Join(arr_path, "\")

    Wscript.echo "New Name: " & strNewName & vbcrlf & "Old Name: " & strPath 
    '!! only for Showing the results

    objFSO.MoveFile strPath, strNewName

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but this brings to me an **Invalid 'exit' statement** in the line with _exit do_

Comment: Thanks a ot for your second script - **It works fine**. Those with Regular Expression object don't work, so I shall always use the other one. **Many thanks** again !!

Comment: @Gurkenhobel If this answer worked for you, [consider accepting this as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)